# Google graph api chart show all values on h axis

Tags: ios, graph, google-visualization, pygooglechart

Hi I am trying to show all values on h axis starts from 12 and ends at 20 shold display like
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20.

I tried using ticks as

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: dataTable.getDistinctValues(0);
}
```

Above line of code does not working.

Below is my current code

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>        <script type="text/javascript"> 
 google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('datetime', 'Dates'); 
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');     data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});  
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');     data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});  
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}}); 
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});  
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});  
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}}); 
 data.addColumn('number','Glucose');    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}}); 

 data.addRows([                            
 [new Date(2014,1,7,11,25,0,0), 110.00, '02 feb - 11:25 | 110.00\\nSunday', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], 
 [new Date(2014,1,7,11,26,0,0), null, null, null, null, 150.00, '04 feb - 11:26 | 150.00\\nTue', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],   
 [new Date(2014,1,7,11,35,0,0), null, null, null, null, null, null, 90.00, '05 feb - 11:35 | 90.00\\nHhgg', null, null, null, null, null, null],   
 [new Date(2014,1,7,11,36,0,0), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 70.00, '06 feb - 11:36 | 70.00\\nHhj', null, null, null, null],  
 [new Date(2014,1,7,11,54,0,0), null, null, null, null, 100.00, '04 feb - 11:54 | 100.00\\nCc', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],  
 [new Date(2014,1,7,13,27,0,0), null, null, null, null, null, null, 258.00, '05 feb - 13:27 | 258.00\\nThu', null, null, null, null, null, null], 
 [new Date(2014,1,7,15,57,0,0), null, null, null, null, 123.00, '04 feb - 15:57 | 123.00\\nGhgggf', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], 
 [new Date(2014,1,7,20,0,0,0), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 120.00, '01 feb - 20:00 | 120.00\\nSat'],    
 [new Date(2014,1,7,20,42,0,0), null, null, 115.00, '03 feb - 20:42 | 115.00\\nMon', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]  
 ]);                  
 var chart = new     google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));  
 chart.setAction({ id: 'sample', text: 'Ver detalles', 
action: function() 
{ 
selection = chart.getSelection(); var selectedRow = selection[0].row;  
window.location.href = "yourapp://"+selectedRow;    
}              
}); 
chart.draw(data,                                                   
 {width: 280, height: 140,                                               
 actionsMenu: {textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:12}},   
 chartArea:{top:20,left:35,width: '85%',height: '70%'}, 
 legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment:'start'},      
 backgroundColor:'transparent',                          
 legend: {position: 'none'},                       
 titleTextStyle:{color: 'black', fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 8}, 
 hAxis: {format: 'H', textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName:   'verdana',fontSize:6},baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor:  'transparent',viewWindowMode:'explicit', viewWindow:{ min: new Date(2014,1,7,11,25,0,0), max: new Date(2014,1,7,20,42,0,0)}},     

 vAxis: {title:'Glucosa',textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:6},baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor: 'transparent'},  
 fontSize: 6,                                      
 tooltip:{textStyle:{color: '#343434', fontName:'verdana',fontSize: 10},trigger: 'selection'},   

 series: {                                                  
 0:{color: '#CCCCCC', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6},   
 1:{color: '#ffff00', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6},  
 2:{color: '#ff0000', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6}, 
 3:{color: '#0000ff', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6},  
 4:{color: '#008000', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6},    
 5:{color: '#696969', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6},   
 6:{color: '#ff00ff', visibleInLegend:true, pointSize:6}   
 },});                           
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function(e) 
 {                            
 var targetType = e.targetID ? e.targetID.split('#')[0] : null;     
 if (targetType && targetType !== 'point' && targetType !== 'action' && targetType !== 'tooltip')
 {                            
 chart.setSelection([]); 
 }                            
 });                            
 }
```

Here is image attached shows output of above code.

[image: outoput of above code]

Answer (score 0):

The list of values returned by `dataTable.getDistinctValues(0)` in your case does not return a list that would create the array you want. This is what is returned by `dataTable.getDistinctValues(0)`:

```
[
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 11, 25),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 11, 26),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 11, 35),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 11, 36),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 11, 54),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 13, 27),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 15, 57),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 20),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 20, 42)
]
```

and this is what the array you want should look like:

```
[
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 12),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 13),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 14),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 15),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 16),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 17),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 18),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 19),
    new Date(2014, 1, 7, 20)
]
```